# Saving model object to database -MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model object and the model object contains many  variables and arrays. i need to save most of the values of model to database  for future use. How can i achieve this? .

I created a table. Is i must insert each and every value individually?..Or is there any other way?

Comment: Why i got down vote???If you put comments,i can improve that in my next posts

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [tutorials here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/data) which illustrate how you could use Entity Framework within your application to map those models to SQL tables and perform queries.